# How to Import All Excel Sheet in Gridview in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created an attendance sheet in excel and i want to display all sheets like class attendance report,students attendance report etc  in gridview,can anybody help me?

Comment: You have multiple sheets ?

Comment: Yes I have 4 sheets in excel.

Answer (score 0):

You should import your sheets into a DataSet object, and then bind it to a GridView.
Take a look at those links:
Excel Sheet to DataSet: [link_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006318/how-to-import-all-the-excel-sheets-to-dataset-in-c-sharp)
Bind DataSet to Gridview: [link_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358799/asp-net-programatically-bind-dataset-to-gridview)

Answer (score 0):

```
   List<string> excelName = new List<string>();   
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();  
   foreach(var name in excelName )
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {        
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string query ="select * from '"+name+"'";
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
            da.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();    
            ds.add(dt);            
        }
    }

    gridview.DataSource = ds;
    gridview.DataBind();
```

Comment: If i supposed to select this file from my system and on button click i wanna see,where i have to write this code?

Comment: @user3069405 You can have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568604/import-excel-data-to-datagridview-in-visual-studio-2010