# how to import excel file data to datagridvidew

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

Hi I have a excel file more than 100000 records i want to import all excel file data to data grid view after import i want to insert specific records to oracle database.for example i want to insert first 5000 records into oracle database.if records successfully insert to database then remove these records from data grid view.Please Guide Me how to achive this

Comment: Maybe this question could help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568604/import-excel-data-to-datagridview-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: We could help you in fixing specific issues but not guide/help in writing entire program. Try some tutorials available in web.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to load the excel file via a date set:

```
Dim XlConnection as OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim adaptor as New OleDBDataAdapter
Dim XlDataset as New Data.DataSet
XlConnection = New OlDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0.;Data Source=" & [File Path])
adapter = New OleDbAdapter("SELECT * FROM Sheet1", XlConnection)
adapter.Fill(XlDataset, [Table Name])
```

Replacing [File Path] and [Table Name] with appropriate strings, you can then either load the datagrid cell by cell or bind the datatable to it - there is plenty of documentation on how to do this out there!

Or you can use the suggestion in the comment above and do it cell by cell direct from the excel file (I prefer the dataset option but that is just my personal opinion!)